# Get textarea value from textarea object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why doesn't this work?. Here the `input` type is `text`:

```
var name = $("input[name='Event[name]']").serializeArray();
name = name[0].value;

var description = $("input[name='Event[description]']").serializeArray();
description = description[0].value;
```

When I want to get the from a `textarea` instead, it doesn't work.

Comment: why do you use array if you have just two fields?

Comment: here many fields i cant use id or jquery it must be javascript

Comment: Why do you post code which uses jQuery when you can't use it?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var name = $("input[name='Event[name]']").val();

var description = $("input[name='Event[description]']").val();
```

Let jQuery handle [`value`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and **textarea**.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  your code as `.val()` to  `.text()`

Comment: -1 `val()` should work. It would be better to use `.val()` and omit the `serializeArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

value isn't a property of a textarea.  Textarea's are nodes that have content.  Use the JQuery attribute for textContent.

Comment: I +1 the answer below, use the `text()` method.

Answer (score 0):

A textarea as no `value` attribute. Use `$("input[name='Event[description]']").val()` since [jQuery folds all values for all kind of input elements](http://api.jquery.com/val/) (input, select, checkbox and textarea) into this function call.

That means you should always use `.val()` to get the value for anything - your code will be more simple and you can even change the type of an input element without breaking anything.

Comment: But he's using `serializeArray()` - not just a jQuery result. For example, try running `$("textarea").serializeArray()[0].value` on this page with the answer box. It definitely has a `.value` property.

Comment: @Yuck: I see no reason for `serializeArray()` in this case.

Comment: I don't see a reason for it either, but since it's being used the resulting object does, in fact, have a `.value` property.

Comment: @Yuck i don't use jquery i cant take value by id . if  i change that case i should be change all project. because all answers don't satisfied me

Comment: @Nurba Your same code **is** using jQuery. The function calls preceded by `$(...)` are jQuery - that's not standard JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason as to why you use get value as array?

If not see below :

```
var name    = $('#name').val();
var description = $('textarea#description').val();
```

considering **name** and **description** is what you have given as id for text field and text area.